# Content not scrolling with scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, firefox, scrollbar

I have recently been tasked with figuring out how to maintain scrollbar positioning for my company's internal SharePoint 2010 site. Unfortunately the out of the box "MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack" doesn't get the result that we want in combination with textbox focusing requirements (including issues with persisted values in hidden fields).

In my most promising solution, I set the scroll value in javascript for the scrolling SharePoint div ('#s4-workspace') so that it is run whenever the browser back/forward buttons are pressed. (In this case I am storing the scroll values in sessionStorage, but I am still experimenting with other persistant media).

I use the following code to reload the scroll position, passing in 's4-workspace' for the main scrollable div in the sharepoint site.

```
function RestoreScrollState(workspaceID) {
    var itemScrollDataIdentifier = pageScrollDataIdentifier + '-' + workspaceID;
    var coordStr = sessionStorage[itemScrollDataIdentifier];
    if (coordStr) {
        var scrollable = $('#' + workspaceID);
        var coords = $.parseJSON(coordStr);
        scrollable.scrollLeft(coords.x);
        scrollable.scrollTop(coords.y);
        return coords;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works great in IE8, IE9, and Chrome, but I am running across a problem in Firefox (17.0.1). When I call this function, the scrollbar is set to the correct position, but the content within the 's4-workspace' div remains scrolled to the top (in other words, the content didn't scroll with the scrollbar). Interestingly enough, if I surround my call to this function in a setTimeout with a two second wait, it scrolls ok (shorter values don't, however).

```
setTimeout(function () { RestoreScrollState('s4-workspace'); }, 2000);
```

I have tried searching around for awhile now, and haven't found anything helpful. Has anyone run into a problem like this, and gotten around it with another workaround aside from a long timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution after banging my head against the wall for a few more hours: it appears that the issue was caused because SharePoint was still in the process of loading its content (from 'sp.js'), and because of the funky things it does with setting up the scrollbar, my script-driven changes must have been applied before the SP scrollbar was completely initialized. So here is what had to be done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runAfterSharePointIsDoneBeingStupid, 'sp.js');
});

function runAfterSharePointIsDoneBeingStupid(){
    //code to persist scrollbar position here
}
```

Please forgive any rude sentiment expressed in my naming...SharePoint and I have a very complicated relationship... ;)